# How to build in parallel (using all cores) with dotnet build command

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, dotnet-cli

Using `msbuild` command I can do:

```
msbuild -m
```

to build with multiple cores.

**Is this possible with `dotnet build` command?**

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) I see:

> dotnet build uses MSBuild to build the project, so it supports both parallel and incremental builds. For more information, see [Incremental Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/incremental-builds).

However, the linked MSBuild documentation only talks about how to enable incremental builds when defining targets and does not mention anything about enabling parallel builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dotnet build` command will default to parallel builds, e.g. the equivalent of using `msbuild -m` or `msbuild -m:1`. You can see this by using the following test project.

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="Test">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="MSBuildNodeCount: $(MSBuildNodeCount)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This results in the following outputs:

```
> msbuild .\test.proj
...
  MSBuildNodeCount: 1
```

```
> msbuild .\test.proj /m
...
  MSBuildNodeCount: 16
```

And for `dotnet build`:

```
> dotnet build .\test.proj
...
  MSBuildNodeCount: 16
```

```
> dotnet build .\test.proj -m:1
...
  MSBuildNodeCount: 1
```

In summary, with MSBuild you default to non-parallel and explicitly enable parallel. In `dotnet build` you default to parallel and can force non-parallel explicitly.

For either tool you can use an explicit value with `-m` (or `-maxcpucount`) to set a specific value and not use the count of all processors.

Answer (score 3):

The [`dotnet build` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) will [accept MSBuild options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#msbuild).

You can do

```
dotnet build -m
```